# Web Browser control crashes

Tags: asp.net

I have a Web Browser object that I to take a screenshot.  The code can be found here: http://www.vbknowledgebase.com/?Id=65&Desc=Convert-Web-Page-or-Html-to-Image (I have modified it a little).

It appears that if I deploy the application locally and then attempt to capture a screenshot of a local page e.g. http://localhost/localpage, the program hangs and does not generate a screenshot.  However, if I deploy the application locally and attempt to generate a screenshot of an external website e.g. http://www.google.co.uk, it works perfectly.

At first I though it was a problem with the STA (single thread apartment), so I posted a question about threading but now I am not so sure.  Are there any issues with the Web Browser object requesting local pages? I have looked on MSDN and on here but cannot find anything conclusive.

Here is the full code:

'ImageFromHTML.vb

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class ImageFromHtml
    Private PageUrl As String = "http://localhost/Default2.aspx"
    Private ConvertedImage As Bitmap

    Private m_intHeight As Integer = 1000
    Public Property Height() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_intHeight
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_intHeight = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_intWidth As Integer = 100
    Public Property Width() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_intWidth
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_intWidth = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Function ConvertPage() As Bitmap
        Me.PageUrl = PageUrl
        Dim thrCurrent As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf CreateImage))
        thrCurrent.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
        thrCurrent.Start()
        thrCurrent.Join()
        ConvertedImage.Save("c:\Test.bmp", _
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
        Return ConvertedImage
    End Function
    Public Sub CreateImage()

        Dim BrowsePage As New WebBrowser()
        BrowsePage.ScrollBarsEnabled = False
        BrowsePage.Navigate(PageUrl)
        AddHandler BrowsePage.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf _
WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted

        While BrowsePage.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
        BrowsePage.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As  _
WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
        Dim BrowsePage As WebBrowser = DirectCast(sender, WebBrowser)
        BrowsePage.ClientSize = New Size(Width, Height)
        BrowsePage.ScrollBarsEnabled = False
        ConvertedImage = New Bitmap(Width, Height)
        BrowsePage.BringToFront()
        BrowsePage.DrawToBitmap(ConvertedImage, BrowsePage.Bounds)

    End Sub

    End Class
```

'Default.aspx.vb

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim obj As New ImageFromHtml()
        obj.ConvertPage()
        obj = Nothing
    End Sub
```

If I change the PageURL variable to an external website e.g. http://www.google.co.uk, it works.  It does not work as it stands above.

Comment: When you deploy the application locally do you have the development server running so that localhost even exists? Might have to put the port too. Never tried publishing on local machine and trying it like this...

Comment: @Nick, thanks.  The application is deployed to IIS locally.  It runs on port 80.

Comment: Please tell me you're not running the web browser _inside_ of an ASP.NET application! What kind of application is hosting the control?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, yes that was my original intention.  I am now thinking about using a Windows form instead.  However, I am still looking for an answer to my original question.  Do you know why the application crashes?

Comment: ***you cannot run the WebBrowser control inside of a server-based application***. It was designed to work in a desktop application.

Comment: @JohnSaunders.  Thanks.  Could you post the link to MSDN with the statement above? I could use it to support my case.

Comment: I don't have a link, just my knowledge of the difference between desktop applications and server applications: the server has no message loop, which most desktop-specific components depend on. Also, server code is usually multithreaded, but desktop applications are more often single-threaded, at least in the sense that there is usually only a single _user_ calling their code. Totally not the case in ASP.NET.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, thanks.  Do you have any idea why the code in my original question crashes? I think I am going to do what you suggest and create a desktop application for this.  This is an intranet application.

Comment: If you're having the problem I think you're having, then this isn't worth debugging. The answer to "why does this happen" will be "because you used it from a server process", and the fix is clear: "don't do that".

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I appreciate what your saying but there appears to be instances where the control is used successfully in ASP.NET e.g. here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50544/Using-the-WebBrowser-Control-in-ASP-NET

Comment: @w0051977: how thoroughly did .test that application? Did they test it under load with multiple simultaneous users? Many things that seem to "work" actually don't work

Comment: @JohnSaunders, it was tested for one user! It is an intranet application and there are many users.  I realise this is not the best approach, but I am just looking for an explanation to my question to expand my knowledge.

Comment: Really, the answer will be "because the control didn't expect multiple threads so it didn't protect against simultaneous access", or "the control was relying on a stream of Windows events, and never got any". BTW, do you realize that this control is, pretty much, Internet Explorer? You're trying to run the browser from inside of a web page being viewed by the browser...

Comment: @JohnSaunders, they are all good suggestions but it doesn't explain why it works requesting an external website.

Comment: You're not going to get an explanation why a piece of code doesn't work in a particular way when you're using it the wrong way. That will be a question of the internal implementation of IE.

Answer (score 0):

web control here is not crash, just throw error messages that you not capture using try-catch schema.

This functions use the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx)  class to read the page and make it bitmap.

so for any reason, maybe the wrong port, not found the server, server return nothing etc, you get an error and you did not handle this error throw. The throw is happens on navigate, and here is an example from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated.aspx

```
' Navigates to the given URL if it is valid.
Private Sub Navigate(ByVal address As String)

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(address) Then Return
    If address.Equals("about:blank") Then Return
    If Not address.StartsWith("http://") And _
        Not address.StartsWith("https://") Then
        address = "http://" & address
    End If

    Try
        webBrowser1.Navigate(New Uri(address))
    Catch ex As System.UriFormatException
        Return
    End Try

End Sub
```

but you can use the try catch before.

### follow up

Focus on this part of your code

```
While BrowsePage.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
    Application.DoEvents()
End While
```

This is not looks logical correct because if the web page is not Compete from an error code, or never load it and the ReadyState is something else for ever, then you stack here and the thread never ends to join the rest! Change this code - I do not know what to tell you here because I do not have this code to debug it, but you can easy place a break point here and see what code make it loop for ever.

### Follow up B

Look at this code

```
ConvertedImage.Save("c:\Test.bmp", _
System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
```

First of all is buggy, and security error code, anyway, the pool probably did not have permissions to write to the root of C drive.

Comment: Yes I have tried wrapping the code in the createimage() function in Try/Catch statement and no exception is thrown.  It appears that the program is trapped in a never ending loop (in the while loop) - see the original question for more information.

Comment: @w0051977 Maybe because is open a new thread and try to attach to it at the end, and never ends because is not read anything. Maybe if you change the code a bit... you write on vb or on c# ?

Comment: thanks.  As I said in the original question; the application works perfectly in Visual Studio (debugging), bu t does not work when deployed to IIS.  I will post some code in the question.

Comment: @w0051977 you say that is hand on localhost, but work on an actual web.

Comment: the application is deployed to IIS (IIS is installed on my local PC).  There is not problem debugging in visual studio.  I will post some code.

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer.  The pool does have access to the C:\.  As I said in my original question; it works perfectly when requesting an external website i.e. it will save to C:\.  I realise there are security issues with the code, but I just wrote something quickily to demonstrate the problem to you.