# ASP.NET - screenshot

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to create a screen shot of the client and store it as a JPEG or something similar?  My original idea was to use the WebBrowser control to create the page on the server side, however this idea was criticised in my last question: [Web Browser control crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435644/web-browser-control-crashes).

Is there a way to use AJAX or another technique without having to buy/use a third party control? I have read plenty of posts on here that talk about AJAX for this but they all seem to recommend third part plugins or contain broken links to tutorials.

This is for an intranet application.  The application is deleting information and the reason for the screenshot is to allow the auditing users to see the deleted information months later i.e. the screenshot is taken before the deletion occurs.

Comment: Would it not be easier to just store the information in archive tables and give the auditors access to that?  What happens if the user has their screen very small at that point and you can't see all the info?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using ASP.Net, is there a programmatic way to take a screenshot of the browser content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220461/using-asp-net-is-there-a-programmatic-way-to-take-a-screenshot-of-the-browser-c)

Comment: @Paddy, there is too much information to store in audit tables.

Comment: @Martin, your post recommends the use of third party plugins.  I am trying to avoid this as stated in my original question.

Comment: This has inspired me to create an online backup service that takes a jpeg of each file opened in notepad.

Comment: @w0051977: The point is that you will have to interact with the browser using some browser or system specific tool that can create the screenshot. HTML, JavaScript or AJAX will not enable to do what you want to achieve.

Comment: There's no such thing as too much information, but there's often inefficient storage.  If you need the data to be accessible, then you need to store it somewhere.  You could even use something like itextsharp to generate a pdf with the data in it, and store it for the auditors - easily done server side.

Answer (score 1):

For a web server to take a screenshot of the client is rude, anti-pattern and as you have seen almost impractical - other than fudging it with browser plugin and then capturing and sending the data. Even HTML5 currently does not allow for such a scenario.

Deleting the information which you talk about, must be done via server (although initiated at the client) so you should have no problem auditing the event at the server when it happens. So taking screenshot is not really necessary.

Comment: when you say: "you should have no problem auditing the event at the server when it happens", are you suggesting using the Web Browser control? If so, then please see my previous post, which was critcised.

Comment: Do you have access to the server-side? Do you want to audit the clients on you can do something at the server too?

Comment: I need a screenshot to show what the users have done i.e. they have options to mark records as deleted or shelved.  A screenshot would be ideal.  There would be a lot of information to store in an audit database.

Comment: There is a difference between what we want and what we need. All you need is a server-side audit so that when such request for deleting comes, this would be logged against the user. Screenshot only adds to the problem: how often do you want to take the screenshot, where to store, ajax for screenshot is a big and heavu call since the image is big.

Comment: Also storing huge audit of every call will not compare to the storing screenshot images.